# How to update in firebase cloud function source code

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a firebase project which has cloud functions, i don't have the original source code and i want to update in the source code.

i tried to follow the documentation of firebase but it create new folder, i don't know how to get the current source code to update it then deploy it.
also i get the source code using "https://console.cloud.google.com/functions" but can't know how to deploy the code after update on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution which i follow:

- Go to the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/getting-started?pli=1) > [Cloud Functions list](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/functions/list?supportedpurview=project).
- Select any of the functions.
- Inside the function's detail, click on the Source tab.
- Then at the bottom, you'll see the "Download.zip" button.
- Then you can make changes,i.e add new function >> add the code for that function and update the index.js (append your work on it to avoid deleting the old functions) then follow the firebase documentation to deploy only one function